# WinError 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host python transfer using sockets

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I'm currently making a file transferring program that reads bytes from the file I want to send, and sends to another computer using a TCP socket.

It works completely normal for smaller files, such as 1~10Kb, but for larger files, I get an error:

> WinError 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I tried adding a `time.sleep(0.00001)` and it works as expected. However, the time used to transfer a single 7MB image skyrockets to 2 minutes (using packages of 500 bytes each).

I wonder if the protocol has any speed limitations because of this?

I have 3 threads sending the same file, using 500/1000/1500 bytes packages to test their efficiency.

Code:

```py
import socket, time, threading
from struct import *

def sending(host, port, path_to_file, package_size):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((host, port))
    send_log = open(f"./Logs/send_log_{package_size}.txt", "w")

    # check if file exists
    try:
        fp = open(path_to_file, "rb")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        sock.close()
        print("File not found")
        return

    sock.send((path_to_file.split(".")[-1]).encode())

    fp = open(path_to_file, 'rb')
    start_time = time.time()
    total_bytes = 0
    package_number = 1
    while True:
        msg = fp.read(package_size - 4)
        if len(msg) < package_size - 4:
            final_result = pack(f'I{len(msg)}s', package_number, msg)
            sock.send(final_result)
            total_bytes += len(final_result)
            send_log.write(f'Package number {package_number} sent with size {len(final_result)}:\n{final_result}\n')
            break
        final_result = pack(f'I{package_size - 4}s', package_number, msg)
        total_bytes += len(final_result)
        send_log.write(f'Package number {package_number} sent with size {len(final_result)}:\n{final_result}\n')
        sock.send(final_result)
        package_number += 1
    time.sleep(0.0000000000001)
    end_time = time.time()
    sock.close()
    print(f"Time elapsed using {package_size} bytes: {end_time - start_time}s, total bytes sent: {total_bytes}")

    return

def receive(host, port, package_size):

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    sock.listen(1)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print("Connection accepted with " + str(addr))

    extension = conn.recv(5).decode()

    log_file = open(f"./Logs/receive_log_{package_size}.txt", "w")
    fp = open(f'./Files/received_file_{package_size}.{extension}', 'wb')
    total_bytes = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    while True:
        received_package = conn.recv(package_size)
        if len(received_package) < package_size:
            package_number, msg = unpack(f'I{len(received_package) - 4}s', received_package)
            total_bytes += len(msg) + 4
            log_file.write(f"Package number {package_number} received with size {len(received_package)}:\n{received_package}\n")
            fp.write(msg)
            break
        package_number, msg = unpack(f'I{package_size-4}s', received_package)
        total_bytes += len(msg) + 4
        log_file.write(f"Package number {package_number} received with size {len(received_package)}:\n{received_package}\n")
        fp.write(msg)


        if not received_package:
            break
    fp.close()
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    log_file.close()
    end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Time elapsed using {package_size} bytes: {end_time - start_time}s, total bytes received: {total_bytes}")
    sock.close()
    return


def main():

    while True:

        try:
            host = input("Enter host: ")
            socket.gethostbyname(host)
            break
        except socket.gaierror:
            print("Invalid host, try again")

    port = int(input("Enter port: "))

    print("We'll transfer the file using the ports:")

    for package_size in range(3):

        print(port+package_size)

    while True:

        mode = input("Enter mode (s or r): ")

        if mode == "s":

            path_to_transfer = input("Enter path to file: ")
            threading.Thread(target=sending, args=(host, port, path_to_transfer, 500)).start()
            threading.Thread(target=sending, args=(host, port+1, path_to_transfer, 1000)).start()
            threading.Thread(target=sending, args=(host, port+2, path_to_transfer, 1500)).start()
            break

        elif mode == "r":
            
            threading.Thread(target=receive, args=(host, port, 500)).start()
            threading.Thread(target=receive, args=(host, port+1, 1000)).start()
            threading.Thread(target=receive, args=(host, port+2, 1500)).start()
            break

        else:

            print("Invalid mode")
            continue

    time.sleep(10)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: why do you open the same file two times? Why not `os.path.exists()` or `os.path.isfile()`

Comment: `send()` doesn't have to send all data as one package. `receiver` may get it as many small packages (and it needs to run `recv()` many times) - and using `if len(received_package) < package_size:` in `receiver` is wrong idea. Better you should  send `len(msg)` before `package_number` and receiver should first read only size and later run loop to repeat `recv()` until it gets expected size.  `while len(received_package) < package_size:`. You can see this in many projects which read from socket